# detect when the channel entries list in control panel has been filtered

Tags: channel-entries, forms, javascript, filtering

I am playing around with a creating an accessory for EE and I am trying to figure out how to run a JavaScript function after the channel entries listing has been filtered.  Any idea how I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better EE way of doing this but I found this little jQuery plugin that seems to work quite well, it detects changes in elements.  So I use it to detect a change in the entry listing table.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233991/jquery-watch-div/3234646#3234646

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid writing an Accessory and just inject the JS into the Control Panel to do it for you using the [CP CSS & JS](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) add-on ([download link](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/cp_css_js)) to inject JS on the filter event?  Hook onto the form submit for #filterform - something like:

```
$("#filterform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do your thing.
});
```

Not sure if that will fire before the ajax or after though. Might have to watch for a change in the top row of the table.